# How to disable file download popup in firefox using selenium and python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to download some reports from web page, using selenium and python

when i click on download link firefox shows save/open dialog

I have used firefox profile configuration as follows

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/pdf,attachment/pdf")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf,attachment/pdf")
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "c:\\firefox_downloads\\")

self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

but still it shows message box,

i have changed

> `self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)`

like above but no chance >

Can any one help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a little helper function which works for me.

It uses chromedriver though.

```
def driver_download(location_for_download):
    # options = Options()
    # options.headless = True
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {'download.default_directory': location_for_download}
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
    # driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)
    return driver
```

Note: For my particular application, I was unable to use the headless. But it should work if its a direct link to the file.

Comment: havent you used firefox?

Comment: @Roshan no, I have tried firefox and it is my preferred browser but for scraping and all I find chrome easier to work with.